# Agente de SQL Server en SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server

Siempre HE realizado Planes de Mantenimiento en Sql Server, siempre los he hecho en 2008 y ahora tengo que realizarlo en 2005. El problema es que no encuentro en Agente de Sql , ¿Como puedo habilitarlo? O de plano no es posible en esta versión de SQL.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 express **no** incluye SQL Agent. Puedes revisar la [documentación acá](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154(v=sql.90).aspx). La parte relevante es:

> However, since SQL Server Express does not ship SQL Agent

(Sin embargo, como SQL Server Express no incluye SQL Agent)

De todas formas, una alternativa sería que crearas un archivo bat, ejecutarlo usando sqlcmd y agendarlo en las tareas programadas de windows.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server Agent no se incluye en la version SQL Server 2005 Express.**

Como una opción podrías usar este desarrollo para crear Jobs en SQL Server 2005 Express desarrollada por [Danillo Corrallo](https://twitter.com/danilo_corallo):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15407/SQL-Agent-A-Job-Scheduler-Framework

Si instalas la versión normal, aquí tienes una **[guía](http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx)** de como habilitarlo en SQL 2005 desde el SQL Service Manager.